# Monads in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, monad

[A monad is an object that has](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/324033/minimal-programmers-definition-of-a-monad):

> 1. A transformation that takes a type and produces a new type. In C# we call such a transformation a "generic type". We have a generic type
>      `M<T>`, we have a type `int`, and we produce a new type `M<int>`.
> 2. A generic function unit which accepts a value of type `T` and produces a value of type `M<T>`.
> 3. A generic function bind which accepts a value of type `M<T>` and a function from `T` to `M<U>`, and produces an `M<U>`.

But what would this look like in a weakly, dynamically typed language like JavaScript?

First attempt:

```
// 1 is not possible because of the typing system?

function monadify(m) {  // `m` is a function
  if(typeof m !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('m must be a function');
  }

  // Returns a function that will apply m to t.
  // "Wraps the value t".
  m.unit = function(t) {  // 2
    return function() { 
      return m(t); 
    };
  };

  // Returns a function that will apply `m` to `t` and then apply `fn` to the result.
  // Binds `fn` to `m`.
  m.bind = function(m, fn) { 
    return function(t) { // 3
      return fn(m(t));
    };
  };

  return m;
}
```

Comment: Douglas Crockford gave a great (or at least interesting) [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0EF0VTs9Dc) on monads in JavaScript.

Comment: The one with the macroid? Yes I may re-visit it.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the "type constructor" part of the definition (which Eric described as a type transformation) isn't really relevant in a dynamically typed language.  So all you really need are the two functions, `unit` and `bind`.  In Javascript, the identity monad might look like this:

```
IdentityMonad = {
    unit: function (val) { 
        return {
            bind: function (f) { return f(val); }
        };
    }
};
```

Using this would look something like:

```
IdentityMonad.unit(4)
             .bind(function (x) { return IdentityMonad.unit(x+1); })
             .bind(function (x) { window.alert(x); });
```

Building actually useful monads is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: I think you meant to use `bind: function (f) { return IdentityMonad.unit(f(val)); }`, otherwise you can't chain the bindings.

Comment: my prior comment may be incorrect as well, I believe `.bind(function (x) { return x + 1; }` is where the actual issue lies, as the function itself should be returning the monad as `.bind(function (x) { return IdentityMonad.unit(x + 1); })` but my knowledge of monads is relatively limited at this point so I could be completely wrong.

Comment: @zzzzBov - Yes, you're quite right... will update answer. :)

Comment: No, he's quite wrong. bind() should return a monadic value. Having `function(x) { return x + 1; }` is totally correct. His first comment about bind returning `unit(f(val))` is correct.

Comment: `function(x) { return x + 1; }` isn't a valid argument to `bind`, but it is a valid argument to `fmap`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partially implemented maybe monad for anyone revisiting.

```
class Maybe {
    isSome;
    val;
    constructor(isSome, val) {
        this.isSome = isSome;
        this.val = val;
    }
    orJust(t) {
        return this.isSome
            ? this.val
            : t;
    }
    map(fn) {
        return new Maybe(this.isSome,
            this.isSome
                ? fn(this.val)
                : null);
    }
    chain(fn) {
        return this.isSome
            ? fn(this.val)
            : new Maybe(false, null);
    }
}

export default {
    some: (val) => new Maybe(true, val),
    none: new Maybe(false, null),
    fromUndef: (val) => !!val && (val) !== NaN
        ? new Maybe(true, val)
        : new Maybe(false, null),
};
```

Comment: I would consider caching/sharing the `none` case.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in JavaScript are monads according to (2) and (3): `flatMap()` is bind and `Array.of()` is return.

Requirement (1) does not really apply to a language without a type notation, but if we use TypeScript we get:

1. `Array<T>` generic type which is instantiated to a specific array type like `Array<number>`.
2. `flatMap()` has the type `Array<T>.flatMap(T=> Array<U>): Array<U>`
3. `Array.of` has the type `Array.Of(T): Array<T>`

Which satisfies the definition.

Whether it is *useful* to think of Array as a monad is a different question. In my opinion, monads are not a very useful abstraction in a language like JavaScript.